# Is there a way to tell if there is key stroke logging software installed?

Tags: windows-xp, security

I have a Windows-XP machine as my desktop system at work.  Is there any way to tell if there is keystroke logging software running on my system or any other software that may be monitoring my system for my activity?

Comment: Discuss this issue with your system administrator.

Answer (score 3):

Ask your admin. Hopefully, you're not the admin.

Answer (score 1):

If you can (or if you're really really paraniod), ctrl-alt-delete and look for processes you're not sure about under Task Manager. Name of the .exe + google is your friend.

Then again, if you think you shouldn't be doing it at work, don't.

If you have agreed to a ToS while using their IT systems they may have a paragraph about keyloggin or screen monitering, but ultimately your IT department should have more important things to worry about.

Comment: It's not necessarily a program that will show up in the processes list; might a device driver for the "keyboard" or something similar. There's plenty of ways to hide what's really going on.

Comment: @Chris, of course this wouldn't protect aginst  a hardware keylogger or something like that, it was just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

No, if a system has been compromised, there is no way to tell while the system is running.

Testing windows from offline media can be very difficult since there isn't really a good source of checksums for all standard files.